# Is there a way to programmatically access OpenSea's assets/orders that are in Matic/Polygon?

Tags: polygon, opensea

I would need to access an asset's orders in OpenSea but their API is not available for Polygon. Their graphql doesn't seem to be open to external calls, and by doing a GET of the asset page itself, I can't access the orders.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this

https://projectopensea.github.io/opensea-js/

It's the SDK and this is an example that they provide.

```
const assets = YOUR_ASSETS
const offer = await seaport.createBundleBuyOrder({
  assets,
  accountAddress,
  startAmount: 2.4,
  // Optional expiration time for the order, in Unix time (seconds):
  expirationTime: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000 + 60 * 60 * 24) // One day from now
})
```

So If nothing is available of chain from the API or SDK. You could alsways find the seaport and fetch it directly. My guess is that the contract must be somewhat standard to opensea so the same call could be made.